# Trouble with JavaScript Eclipse editor. It doesn't see what should see

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm using standard js plugin to eclipse. I have something like this:

Images.js:

```
Images = function() {};

Images.prototype = {
    load: function(){
        // code...
    }
};
```

Game.js:

```
Game = function() {
    this.images = {};
};

Game.prototype = {
    init : function() {
        var self = this;
        self.images = new Images();
        self.images. // press ctrl+space
    }
};
```

When I press ctrl+space after 'self.images.' I would like it suggests me 'load' method, but it doesn't see it. Is it possible to fix it?